# Determine whether on shop page in woocommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

My client wants the checkout to be "streamlined" to skip the cart page and go straight to checkout one product at a time. I got that covered but I also need to automatically empty the cart if the customer decides not to confirm checkout.

For this I wanted to check whether or not I'm on any other page than cart or checkout and do it there but all the commands I tried (is_shop(), is_front_page(), is_page('Shop'), is_product(), is_home()) always return false so I'm not sure what to do about it. This is how I'm trying to do it (in my themses functions.php):

```
function reset_cart_front() {
  global $woocommerce;
    echo "Attempting to empty<br>";

    if (is_shop()) { 
        echo "is right page<br>"; 
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
    } else {
        echo "is not right<br>";
    }

}
add_action( 'init', 'reset_cart_front' );
```

what gives?

Comment: `init` is too early for doing any conditional logic tests such as `is_shop()` as the query vars haven't been set up yet.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I figure it out!

```
function reset_cart_shop_loop() {
    global $woocommerce;
    $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart();
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop', 'reset_cart_shop_loop' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong...but I think you should check if the current page [`is_checkout()`](https://github.com/woothemes/woocommerce/blob/541edc35705cc5ca1b20f6dd8f09a09a07bb944d/includes/wc-conditional-functions.php#L93), and empty the cart if it's not:

```
function reset_cart_front() {
    global $woocommerce;

    if ( !is_checkout() ) { 
        $woocommerce->cart->empty_cart(); 
    }

}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'reset_cart_front' );
```

I also think `'init'` is too early to hook (and would recommend trying [`'template_redirect'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/template_redirect)).